# Datatable per cell dropdown condition

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Is there a way to configure dropdown option for datatable to target specific cells. I looked into documentation https://dash.plot.ly/datatable/dropdowns 12 and could only see per-entire-column and per-entire-row.

What i need is to be able to have custom dropdowns for specific cells. For example:

c00 | c01 | c02
c10 | c11 | c12
c20 | c21 | c22

c02 to have dropdown with options 0123, c12 to not have dropdown since it is not null, and c22 to have dropdown with options 0123.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one, as there is no way (to my knowledge at least) where you can index the row using the `dropdown_conditional` attribute's `filter_query` key.

What you could do is that you add an auxiliary column for row IDs, and then use the `filter_query` to specify cells you wish to have dropdowns for. Then, when you display the datatable, you hide this auxiliary column by not including it in the `DataTable.columns` attribute. This depends on how you initially populate the datatable, so this can serve your purpose if you manage it carefully. This assumed you know the columns name as the position. Here is an example of how you specify the first column's (called "climate" here) first cell (indexed as  1) to have a dropdown:

```py
from dash import Dash, dash_table, html
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict


app = Dash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([
    ('row_id', [1,2,3,4]),
    ('climate', ['Sunny', 'Snowy', 'Sunny', 'Rainy']),
    ('temperature', [13, 43, 50, 30]),
    ('city', ['NYC', 'Montreal', 'Miami', 'NYC'])
]))


app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='table-dropdown',
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        columns=[
            {'id': 'climate', 'name': 'climate', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
            {'id': 'temperature', 'name': 'temperature'},
            {'id': 'city', 'name': 'city', 'presentation': 'dropdown'},
        ],

        editable=True,
        dropdown_conditional=[{
            'if': {
                'column_id': 'climate',
                'filter_query': '{row_id} eq 1'
            },
            'options': [
                {'label': i, 'value': i}
                for i in [
                    'Very Cold',
                    'Freezing'
                ]
            ]
        }]
    ),
    html.Div(id='table-dropdown-container')
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Can I ask another question? What if I have a list of row IDs that I wish to have a dropdown for each row on the same table? For example. I want row IDs [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8] or more.

Comment: In the df:
`df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([
    ('row_id', [1,2,3,4]),
    ('climate', ['Sunny', 'Snowy', 'Sunny', 'Rainy']),
    ('temperature', [13, 43, 50, 30]),
    ('city', ['NYC', 'Montreal', 'Miami', 'NYC'])
]))`
You can add the rows ids you want. These don't have to be numbers, but at least unique identifiers (so even strings like dictionarys). As long as you append a column of IDs, then you can index the cells in some fashion

Comment: I have the per-cell dropdown working as described above.  But I would like to set a default value for each dropdown.  Based on the documentation, it appears that I should add a 'value': <default> item to each element of the dicts in the dropdown_conditional list.  But when I do, I get an "Invalid Component" exception.  Is there a work-around?  Thanks.

Comment: R: @mwrowe I figured this out-- you just set the values of the cells in the data property directly (as a separate output of the callback) at the same time you define the dropdown options.